# Same alias for SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, alias

I am using SQL Server 2012 and now I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on my machine. I have both SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012 running on my machine.

And I already have created an alias for SQL Server 2012 as 'serverhost\sql',
and now it I require to create an alias for SQL Server 2008 R2 with same name as 'serverhost\sql'.

And when I am trying to connect to database using `serverhost\sql`, user get connected to database but to SQL Server 2012 not SQL Server 2008 R2.

I don't know that: we are able to create alias with same name for 2 diff server instances on same machine.

Is It possible?

if yes then how would I achieve this?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you have a single alias "mapped" to two different SQL Server instances'??

Comment: i am working on one project with sql server 2012 but now its needed to work with sql server 2008 r2, and i dont want to change the config settings

Comment: Yes, but you haven't answered my question: if you have the **same alias** pointing to **two database instances** at the same time - what do you expect to happen? Basically, my take on this: you **cannot** do this. You **cannot** have two identical aliases, pointing to two different instances. You can have **one alias at a time** - if you need to switch, you need to **drop the old alias** (on e.g. SQL Server 2012) and then create the new one on SQL Server 2008 R2 - then you're redirected to SQL Server 2008 R2 ....

Comment: Okay @marc_s ... thanks can i ask one more question???... I have used 1433 for both servers ... is it ok?? ...  means it would not make any issue if i use same port for both.

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue at all - I have up to four instances on a single dev machine, all on the default port

Comment: okay.... thanks @marc_s